# Name for introductory section about the author

Tags: forewords

What is an appropriate title for an introductory section where I introduce myself, the author?

I'm writing a series of short educational web books for learning to do web development, and I want to include a section in the first book where I introduce myself. I'm having difficulty with the title for this section, though. Normally, I'd just use the word "introduction" -- but I'm already using  using that for the section actually introducing the topic.

What's the typical name for a section like this?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Stack Exchange is not a discussion board, we require clear, answerable questions which have the potential to help others. This is a "what to write" question and is therefore off-topic for us. Please see our help center writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: IMHO this is asking about correct naming for a particular type of section, which personally I'd see as on-topic. Other authors with similar sections will find this useful.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest *About the Author* or *Preface*.

Comment: I'll second "About the Author," although it's usually at the end, not the beginning.

Comment: There is also *Foreward*. It kind of depends on how important it is for your readers to know you {e.g., if it were a story about forgiveness, is it being written perhaps by a priest}, is there supplemental material being presented about the story {where research was done, local customs, etc.}, or if a particular expertise is expected by the reader {we would anticipate a series of educational videos being presented by at least a Master level in that field}.

Comment: I agree that "About the Author" typically adorns the back of a manuscript, but I've seen it in both places.

Honestly, depending on tone, I wouldn't mind seeing a humorous heading like "So, who is this guy, anyway, and why should I listen to him?"